# How can I format a string when I use data binding?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

`aDetailViewModel.size` is `LivaData<Int>`, the Code A displays the size of a file, it works well.

I hope to display  a unit for the szie, but Code B doesn't work, how can I fix it?

**Code A**

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvFileSizeValue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/myDetailContent"
            android:text="@{String.valueOf(aDetailViewModel.size)}" />
```

**Code B**

```
 <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvFileSizeValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/myDetailContent"
                android:text="@{String.valueOf(aDetailViewModel.size)+ "Kb"}" />
```

**Added Content**

Thanks!

The following code can works well.

But is there more simply way?

```
<string name="formatSizeToString">%1d KB</string>   

android:text="@{@string/formatSizeToString(aDetailViewModel.aMVoiceForEdit.size)}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use static function and call it in you xml. for example in file
StringFormatter.kt

```
fun formatString(size: Int): String {
   return "$size kb"
}
```

and then in you xml you can import it

```
<layout>
<data>
   <import type="com.path.to.the.package.StringFormatter" />
    // your viewmodel variable here
    // etc
</data>
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvFileSizeValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/myDetailContent"
                android:text="@{StringFormatter.formatString(aDetailViewModel.size)}" />

</layout>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a more simply way?

Comment: I am not sure there is more simple way

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?